# HTML/CSS 'width: 100%' not filling entire space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the nav bar width 100%, so stretch across the screen. I'm doing this, but it's not working:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

div#header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0;
}

/*
#222222 - top nav
#F5F5F5 - sidebar background color
#FFF - sidebar link hover background color
#63B7E8 - sidebar nav link hover text color
#D8D8D8 - sidebar nav text color
*/


/* Navigation */

/* Nav Title */
.nav
{
    background-color: dimgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav-items">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is what it's doing: https://gyazo.com/a8cbf7530ccfa46f01a603e1c7dcb465
Any idea what it's only stretching part way?

Comment: I tried removing     <div class="container">, and it stretched the full lenght. Is this a bootstrap implemented thing already, to shorten the container?

Comment: Your div with class '.container' has a width that is smaller than the whole page. because of this it's constricting.

Answer (score 3):

The `container` class is limited in [`bootstrap.css`](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

All child elements refer to this `width` as `100%`.

Tip for the future: Get yourself comfortable with your browser's DOM inspection tools:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Add-ons/DOM_Inspector
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

As **Marvin** stated, the width is limited because of `<div class="container">` being there.

So, you have the option to change your markup like this:

```
<div id="header">
</div>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-items">

        </div>
    </div>
```

To have `width: 100%` for your `<div class="nav-items">`.

## BUT

But if you are after something similar in which the navigation background is extended in full width, but menu items still wrapped in `container`, you may do it like this:

```css
#header{
  height: 40px;
}
.nav-bg{
  background-color: #7878EF;
}
.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav{
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.nav .nav-items{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
    
<div class="nav-bg">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="nav">
       <div class="nav-items">Nav Item</div>
       <div class="nav-items">Nav Item</div>
       <div class="nav-items">Nav Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    This is body content. This is body content. This is body content. This is body content. This is body content. This is body content. This is body content. This is body content. 
</div>
```